# How to delete files I copied before?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a GTAV mod patcher.
In order for this to work I already wrote a code to copy the mods into the GTA Folder.

```
If TextBox1.Text = Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show("Select your Folder first!")
Else
    If Not Directory.Exists(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Path is Invalid")
    Else
        Dim pathGTAV As String = TextBox1.Text
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(pathMods, TextBox1.Text, True)
        MessageBox.Show("Mods Injected Succesfully!")
    End If
End If
```

Now I just need a way to only delete the files I copied  already. So basically I just need a way to memorize the files I moved, so I can delete them later on.

Comment: If that's [tag:vba], the `Kill` keyword would do it. If you're in [tag:visual-studio] then this is probably [tag:vb.net] and you would use the framework's `File` type and its static methods to do it. I'm not sure about [tag:vbscript], but AFAIK if it works in VBA then it works in VBScript too. Point is, you have 3 tags here, potentially refererring to 3 different languages: I suggest you [edit] your post and its tags to clarify.

Comment: What qualifies a "file you copied already"?

Comment: Use File.Move https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: I'm copying files into the folder with the exe of GTA. Now I need a way to seperate the files I move to the folder from the exe and other game-files, so I can delete the mods if I want to.